# How to simplify Sign'

Tags: wolfram-mathematica, simplification

How can I force Mathematica to simplify the derivative of Sign? The following

```
    FullSimplify[D[Sign[x], x], x > 0]
```

does not work. All it produces is

```
    Sign'[x]
```

(On the other hand,

```
    FullSimplify[D[Abs[x], x], x > 0]
```

goes through.)

Answer (score 0):

The Mathematica Sign function can handle complex numbers. This complicates things. If your implementation is only relevant for real numbers, it might be better to use RealSign[] because that is differentiable.

I had a similar issue and found this information in the reference pages:
https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Sign.html